# Verify servers in text file with openssl

Tags: bash, openssl

I want to verify a list of servers in a text file with openssl but i got an error, i don't know why, here is my code and the error message:

**code:**

```
#!/bin/bash
input="path/file"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo "$line"
  openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 5 -connect "$line":443
done < "$input"
```

**Error message :**

```
error:2008F002:BIO routines:BIO_lookup_ex:system lib:../openssl-1.1.1g/crypto/bio/b_addr.c:726:H
connect:errno=11001
```

any help please! thank you in advance.

Comment: What does the input file contain? If you add `set -x` to the script, which line of the file does it fail on?

Comment: it's a text file contains servers like www.google.com,www.youtube.com
the echo shows the line but the command fails openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 5 -connect "$line":443, when i replace $line by www.google.com it works but not with file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text file was created under windows. It contains CrLf at end of every line. You can convert this file into the correct line ending, for example with

```
dos2unix filename
```

Comment: yes you are right!! it works after converting the file , thank you so much